Godot 4 FPS air strafe mechanics
i'm working on a playerController script in gdscript for a FirstPersonShooter.
What i'm tring to implement is a kinda of air-strafe but only in forward direction of the character (like the valorant one if someont have played it).
The problem is that whit this code the air-strafe seems to be working only on the axes the world, in fact when i rotate the character of 90° the air_lateral_movement and the air_forward_movement "switch functionality"
func handle_movement(delta):
    var input_dir = Input.get_vector("move_left", "move_right", "move_forward", "move_backward")
    var direction = (transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y)).normalized()
    
    if is_on_floor():
        if direction:
            velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, direction.x * move_speed, delta * ground_lateral_friction)
            velocity.z = lerp(velocity.z, direction.z * move_speed, delta * ground_forward_friction)
        else:
            velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, 0.0, delta * ground_lateral_friction)
            velocity.z = lerp(velocity.z, 0.0, delta * ground_forward_friction)
    else:
        velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, direction.x * move_speed, delta * air_lateral_movement)
        velocity.z = lerp(velocity.z, direction.z * move_speed, delta * air_forward_movement)
    move_and_slide()

